# How to do inline editing in angularjs without Template?

Tags: angularjs, inline-editing

am trying to write an inline editing function without using a template as outlined here
http://plnkr.co/edit/EsW7mV?p=preview

Comment: It might help to understand what you are trying to achieve by writing your directive without a template?  There are a couple of ways of going about it (a template is probably the best way, however) but without knowing what you are trying to achieve, I don't know which approach to show.

Comment: So what we have to do here?

Comment: Template is the best way, i agree. But when we have dynamic values, template turns out to be a big problem. So what i am looking for is an example of in-line editing that does not use a template. Hope this helps.

Comment: well u have to write the HTML somewhere, and ur options as far as i know r (1) like u did (2) in the directive write html instead the url of the template (3) inside the link func start writing relevat html. i do believe that what u did is the "best practice"

Answer (score 6):

You can just place the code of the template in the main page.

```
<li ng-repeat="todo in todos" inline-edit="todo.title" on-save="updateTodo(todo.title)" on-cancel="cancelEdit(todo.title)">
  <div>
  <input type="text" on-enter="save()" on-esc="cancel()" ng-model="model" ng-show="editMode">
  <button ng-click="cancel()" ng-show="editMode">cancel</button>
  <button ng-click="save()" ng-show="editMode">save</button>
  <span ng-mouseenter="showEdit = true" ng-mouseleave="showEdit = false">
    <span ng-hide="editMode" ng-click="edit()">{{model}}</span>
    <a ng-show="showEdit" ng-click="edit()">edit</a>
  </span>
  </div>
</li>
```

Here there is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/siliconball/QwDn9/2/

Also temeber to take away the `templateUrl: 'inline-edit.html'`

If you need the controller scope for any reason place `scope: false` in the directive. But then you will have to track which option are you editing in any moment (maybe using the id). If that is your situation i suggest to refactor a bit, as you may know, probably is not the best option.

If your situation, i guess it is, is that you want to write it all in one page because you are generating it through some CGI or dynamic content script and you don't want to write the same code in different pages (+scripts interfaces ...), then i suggest also to move the `inline-edit="todo.title"` and all the directive stuff in the `<div>` for the sake of orthogonality.

Comment: They all have `ng-model="model"`, I don't understand why it supports multiple editing at the same?